# Pigeon hole principle doubt

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

Question

Of 12 distinct two digits numbers we can select 2 with a two digit difference of the form aa

Can anyone please explain me what this question means

Comment: Meaning : Given any set of twelve numbers, all of which have two digits, it is possible to select two of them, say $p$ and  $q$, such that $p-q$ is a two digit number having the same digits (i.e. of the form $aa$). For example, $67 - 23 = 44$ is of the form $aa$, and $81 - 18 = 63$ is not. What the question is asking you to show is that you can find two numbers exhibiting the property that $67$ and $23$ showed i.e. their difference is of the form $aa$.

Comment: Hint: Residue classes modulo eleven. Urgent advice: [Read the guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг   Very very thanks for the explanation

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am sorry for the bad question. I hope to rectify my fault from the next time

Comment: @user606630  You are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement says that in any set of twelve distinct two digit numbers (i.e. twelve numbers between $10$ and $99$ where no two are the same) then there are two numbers whose difference (absolute value of one minus the other) is a multiple of $11$.

Presumably the associated question is asking you to prove this.

To apply the pigeon hole principle, put the twelve numbers into pigeon holes that represent the remainder when each number is divided by 11. What can you conclude about the difference of two numbers if they re in the same pigeon hole ?